# Can't get PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to work the way I want

Tags: spring, configuration

I'm trying to use PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer to read my app configuration. Basically there is a first configuration file in `WEB-INF/config/config.properties` that contains the filesystem location of another properties file (so that it is not destroyed during app deploy or update). I'm trying to have this set up in `servlet-context.xml` but only the first one works:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurerInternal"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="location">
        <value>/WEB-INF/config/config.properties</value>
    </property>
</bean>


<bean id="propertyConfigurerExternal"
    class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer"
    depends-on="propertyConfigurerInternal">
    <property name="location">
        <value>file:${baseDataFolder}/jaccise.conf</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

The first one (`propertyConfigurerInternal`) is created with no problem, but the second one fails like this:

> `org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanInitializationException`: Could not load properties; nested exception is `java.io.FileNotFoundException`: `${baseDataFolder}\jaccise.conf` (Impossibile trovare il percorso specificato) <- Means "Can't find file in specified path"

like the EL expression is not working... How do I solve this?

Comment: I don't think you can do this. All of the `PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer` beans are initialized together, and *then* the substitution takes place. So they can't refer to each other.

Comment: then how would you solve somthing like this?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
<bean id="propertyConfigurer" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations">
        <list>
            <value>/WEB-INF/config/config.properties</value>
            <value>file:${baseDataFolder}/jaccise.conf</value>
        </list>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Just use a single PlaceholderConfigurer and see if that is the cause of your problem. I've never seen two instances being created like you're attempting and I'm guessing that this can be problematic.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

`depends-on="propertyConfigurerInternal"` means that `propertyConfigurerInternal` is initialized before `propertyConfigurerExternal`.

And `${baseDataFolder}` must be included in the property files of `propertyConfigurerInternal` (in your case: `config.properties`), otherwise it cannot be parsed.

So, you should have a look at your `/WEB-INF/config/config.properties` to see whether `${baseDataFolder}` was set within the file.